# Square, Triangle, and House Program Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I need to have a program that asks the user if they want to see a drawing of a square, a triangle, or a house.  The program needs to display the appropriate drawing. If the user enters and improper entry, an error message should be displayed.  To draw the house, the program needs to reuse the square and triangle code.  This is what I have so far, I am unsure how to combine the parts to create the house.  Any help?

```
m, n = 10, 10
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print('*' if i in [0, n-1] or j in [0, m-1] else ' ', end='')
    print()

m, n = 10, 10
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print('*' if i in [j, m-1] or j == 0 else ' ', end='')
    print()
```

I do not understand where to go from here.  I am not asking for someone to write my code, but to help or at least guide me on how to combine them for the house or to help complete the program im trying to finish writing. Thanks

Comment: Need more info. What does that output and what *should* the output look like?

Answer (score 2):

You should move your routines into functions

```
def square(m, n):
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            print('*' if i in [0, n-1] or j in [0, m-1] else ' ', end='')
        print()

# Do the same for triangle


square(10,10) # This will print a square
```

Then you can define a function `house` which prints a triangle on top of a square.

```
def house(m, n):
    triangle(m, n)
    square(m, n)
```

You might need to change your triangle code slightly to make it look more houselike